# Paper.JS create another function to draw a path

Tags: javascript, paperjs

So I'm trying to read data and then pass that to another function so I can draw a path. 
The data is fine, it's all working and I can view it in the console.

The normal drawing (Using the `onMouseEvent`) functions work fine.

The only way I can get it to draw using a different function, is if I declare the path at the top of the JS file:
`var reloadPath = new Path();`

The problem with this, is that when I call `reloadPath`, it automatically connects the lines (even if the user has clicked elsewhere) which is what I don't want.

I've tried `var reloadPath;` at the start of the file, and then this

```
function reloadDrawing(data) {
    reloadPath = new Path();
    reloadPath.strokeColor = 'black';
    reloadPath.add(data);
    view.draw();

}
```

But this just doesn't draw anything.

Thanks.

edit:

Tried the amendments but they didn't work. I'm using Jade instead of HTML (using node.js) so theres really nothing in my html: using socket.io as well
JS:

```
This does all the dynamic drawing stuff
io.on( 'reloadDrawing', function( data ) {
    console.log("fired");
    endDrawing(data);
    startDrawing(data);

});

function endDrawing(data){
  reloadPath.add(data);
  view.draw();
  reloadPath = new Path();
}

function startDrawing(data) {
  reloadPath = new Path();
  reloadPath.strokeColor = 'black';
  reloadPath.add(data);
  view.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you overwrite the `reloadPath` and thus destroy the data that's already there. Delete the one line and add another function `endDrawing` (or any name you like). Call this new function in the `onMouseUpEvent`, in order "finish" the line. In the `onMouseDown`-event start a new line using the `startDrawing` function.

```
function reloadDrawing(data) {
  reloadPath.add(data);
  view.draw();
}

function endDrawing(data){
  reloadPath.add(data);
  view.draw();
  reloadPath = new Path();
}

function startDrawing(data) {
  reloadPath = new Path();
  reloadPath.strokeColor = 'black';
  reloadPath.add(data);
  view.draw();
}
```

Comment: This joins the lines  though, which is what I don't want.  For example if someone draws a rectangle on the left side, then draws a rectangle on the right side. It will connect both of these rectangles

I think I need to overwrite the reloadpath data so it creates a new path every time but I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer. You need to capture the `onMouseUp` event and end the old line there, and start a new one.

Comment: Thanks, but I've made the amendments but it is still joining the paths together

Comment: Can you make sure, the `onMouseUp` is fired and the end-function is executed?

Comment: I've thrown console.log's in each and they both print the text.

Comment: I've added a `startDrawing` function, which should be called in the `onMouseDown`-event. Can you share a "minimal working example" of your html and javascript?

Comment: You did not call the two functions in the proper handlers.

Comment: The normal drawing of the function works, I can't re-use the original handlers as I'm dynamically drawing the path.

Comment: The problem is that you add the same point in endDrawing and startDrawing.